# Photos getting dark pack camera

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, android-camera

I'm using the camera pack, however, the photos are getting too dark, does anyone know how to lighten them, note: I'm not using image_picker, because I need the front camera as the main one and the device doesn't have a flash.

https://pub.dev/packages/camera

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making the resolution to `UltraHigh` or a better clarity?

`controller = CameraController(cameras[1], ResolutionPreset.UltrHigh;`

the above is placed in init function and try setting image clarity as high as possible, you can surely take a look at [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin

Regards,

Rosahn

Comment: hello, but as I increase the brightness, because this setting only increases the resolution.